# C++/CLI syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request

Since it's come up, and it's worth distinguishing it from [c++](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), I've added a [c++cli](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2bcli) tag to the site. It doesn't trigger C++ syntax highlighting though.

I request that the [c++cli](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2bcli) tag offer C++ syntax highlighting.

Comment: Probably this should also apply to the eventual C++/CX (used by WinRT in Metro) tag that surfaces.